# Setting fps of output video equal to input video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a screencaptured video that has a weird framerate (58.7305122).
I want to create a lower resolution version of this video with the exact same framerate. I know that I can use the -r switch to set the framerate and type in this manually. However if I want to work on a couple of videos or I wanna use this in a python script this a litte tiresome / not practicable.

Is there a variable that delivers the framerate of the input video which I can use as an argument for the -r switch of the output video?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `-vsync 0` to your command. Don't add `-r`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this one. However I get an error message with this.
I tried :
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vsync 0 OUTPUT.mp4
Then i get an error:
[mpeg4 @ "some hex number"] Invalid pts (18) <= last (18)

Comment: Then change to `-vsync vfr` but in this case, input frames with identical timestamps will be adjusted so that output rate will be slightly different.

Comment: Yea this doesn't help me then because I edit the video frame by frame therefore I need them in sync ... :(